# python interpreter defaulting to conda environment - Windows

Tags: python, anaconda

I have ananconda installed on my Windows PC as well as python 3.10.
I created a virtual environment using venv in python (not using conda). Here's what my interpreter setup looks like.

[image]

Now I am trying to open up my command line python and import a python file that I've created.  When I open my command prompt and type "Python" I am getting my anaconda base environment every time.

[image]

I'd like to be able to import my file and then modify the file. I have added the virtual environment, and 3.10 to the windows environment PATH location, but again its always defaulting as Anaconda... Im not sure how to switch it.  My goal is to be able to import a file that I created from the virtual env into the command line interpreter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is your "interpreter setup" that you are showing in that first image?

Comment: yah I had some confusion about that too I ended up installing a fresh version of python 3.9.7, setting that to PATH and restarting. That seems to have done it! When I type python in the cmd prompt it no longer defaults to the anaconda version !